# Using a HTML button to call and pass information to a PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following code in which I am trying to display some information from an SQL Database, print it and have a button next to this information which would allow me to call a PHP Function. I am aware that you can not simply call a PHP function from HTML as PHP is server side. However all of the other answers seem to assume a knowledge of AJAX/ javascript which I do not have. My code is as follows:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()){


            /* return the results */
            $links .= 'Website Name: '. $row['title'].'<br>';
            $links .= "Link        : <a href= " . $row['link'] . " > " . $row['link'] ." </a> </br>";
            $links .= "Recommendations: " . $row['recommendations'] . "</br></br>"; 
            }

        return $links;
```

I add each bit of information, pre formatted, to the `$links` variable and then return this to be accessed in a different file. Originally, I thought I would be able to do something similar to this

```
$links .= 'Website Name: '. $row['title'].'<button onClick="recommend($row[id])" /><br>';
```

However this requires a Javascript function `recommend` to be called and I do not have any knowledge of Javascript. For this reason, I can think of no other way of solving this problem. I am sorry if I have not explained my issue well enough and will be happy to provide any extra information you may want. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: your best bet: use a __form__

Comment: Can you give us more information on what the PHP function does when it is called?

Comment: @Nate the function would just be used to update an SQLite3 entry. This is the reason `id` must be passed through so I know which link the user has recommended

Comment: @itachi I can not think of a viable way of using a form and positioning it next to each link, creating a possibly infinite number of forms and tracking which link each form relates to.

Comment: .... that's why you need to learn ajax. (broadly, javascript).

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/, it is exactly what you need and it will work you to the JQuery, which is a simplyfied JavaScript. Don't forget to implement JQuery version using `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a non-ajax answer for you.

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()){


        /* return the results */
        $links .= 'Website Name: '. $row['title'].'<br>';
        $links .= "Link        : <a href= " . $row['link'] . " > " . $row['link'] ." </a>    </br>";
        $links .= "Recommendations: " . $row['recommendations'] . "</br></br>"; 
        $links .= "<a href='update.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'> Recommend </a>";
        }

    return $links;
```

Then on update.php add the code to process the id from the $_GET array and redirect back to the original page.

That way you can stick to php and not worry about AJAX/Javascript

Comment: Thank you for the very simplistic answer. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to change the content of the page dynamically, which is only possible with Javascript or something similar.

The only other way to achieve something similar is to have an iframe in the page. A link could then be loaded in that iframe and request a page from the server without affection the parent page.

```
<iframe name="functionLoader" width="1" scrolling="no" height="1" frameborder="0" src="doNothing.php" seamless="seamless"></iframe>

<a href="phpScriptToExecute.php" target="functionLoader">Execute Script</a>
```

Still, this is a rather dirty workaround. I would suggest you to look at JavaScript and AJAX, even if it takes some time to get into.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a form instead of a button.

Replace

```
<button onClick="recommend($row[id])">
```

with

```
<form action="some_php_page"><input type="hidden" value="$row[id]" name="PICK_A_NAME"><input type="submit" value="WHATERVER_U_WANT_THE_BUTTON_TO_SAY"></form>
```

So when the button is clicked the page will post the hidden field value on a php page where you can save it in the database and after that return the user to the page where you list the websites for recommendation.

Not sure how good of a solution this will be because anyone can recommend a website multiple times. I guess you have to adjust it so that it will reflect the website logic.